# Dahlin_Controller ringing and saturation

Tags: circuit-design, control-system, motor-controller

I have designed a digital controller to control a DC motor. The motor has the following parameters:

```
J = 0.01;                           % moment of inertia of the rotor       0.01 kg.m^2
b = 0.1;                            % motor viscous friction constant      0.1 N.m.s
K = 0.01;                           % electromotive force constant         0.01 V/rad/sec
                                    % motor torque constant                0.01 N.m/Amp
R = 1;                              % electric resistance                  1 Ohm
L = 0.5;                            % electric inductance                  0.5 H
s = tf('s');
P_motor = K/((J*s+b)*(L*s+R)+K^2)   % Open loop Transfer function of a Dc motor Speed/Voltage
```

I have used a Dahlin controller to control this motor with:

```
Ts=0.05;
k=2;
q=1;
Tz=((z^(-k-1))*(1-exp(-Ts/q)))/(1-(exp(-Ts/q))*z^(-1));
Dz=(1/(dP_motor))*(Tz/(1-Tz));

sys_cl_4 = feedback(Dz*dP_motor,1);
[x4,t] = step(sys_cl_4,8);
stairs(t,x4);
xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ylabel('Velocity (rad/s)')
title('Stairstep Response: with Dahlin controller')
```

The transfer function of the Dahlin controller is:

```
      0.04877 z^6 - 0.1201 z^5 + 0.09688 z^4 - 0.02546 z^3
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0.002059 z^7 - 0.002231 z^6 - 0.001445 z^5 + 0.001539 z^4 + 7.821e-05 z^3
```

The response of the motor to step input is fine, but I have some questions regarding this controller:

- The controller output goes up to 23.68 for 1rad/s (Step input),which can be considered as a saturation.
- The controller rings (oscillates) and it is undesirable as far as I know.
- The first graph is the step response of the closed loop system.
- The second graph is the output of the controller in the time domain.

[image]

My question:

- How should I proceed, and what considerations should I take to avoid the saturation of the controller output.
- What makes this controller rings (oscillates), even though this controller is well known

Comment: What are the axes on both graphs X and Y? What is your sampling rate? Have you tried tweaking the coefficients?

Comment: @Andyaka, the sampling rate is Ts=0.05s, The first graph is step response of the closed loop system and the second is the time domain output of the Dahlin controller

Comment: FYI: see [my answer to the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4662193/76466) on math SE.